# Issue while accessing Groups from Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to access the Joined Groups from Microsoft Graph API,
I have done the Azure AD authentication and able to get the required access token.

The access token is working when I read the data from SharePoint OData endpoints but I am not able to access the URL

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams
```

I tried to access using PostMan client and it gives me the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ef4be9c8-27c7-40e7-8157-c08848f5132f",
      "date": "2018-03-13T09:46:11"
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to access this URL using javascript code then I got the different error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid version",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "51113cc5-2963-4e0f-bf70-6e080a8f5671",
      "date": "2018-03-13T09:29:18"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with different permission set, even with administrative access but no luck.

I also tried to access

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/
```

it is working in the PostMan Client but, not working in the JavaScript (I got the same error).

Tere is the header I use to send Request

```
var header = {
  Authorization: "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>",
  Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false"
};
```

Can Anyone suggest What things I missed or What permission I should use?

These permission require admin consent, are these the correct permissions?

[image]

**Update 2**
I tried to use admin consent, grant all required permission to the app(AD app). below are the scope data extracted from jwt.io

```
    "scp": "email Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All openid User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite.All"
    "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
```

I am using administrator account with all permissions. 
but no luck, still I am getting **"Error authenticating with resource."**
but using the token I can access the URL

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

and in response, I am getting all the details of Admin

I tried to read all the documentation available for that but no luck

Comment: You could check the token at https://jwt.ms. Double-check the audience (`aud`) is `https://graph.microsoft.com`, and that one of the required scopes (`scp`) or roles (`roles`) is there.

Comment: "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com/", and  "scp": "Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All",

Comment: @SunilSoni The scopes for joinedTeams graphAPI will be User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All.  please go through the link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams for more information

Comment: I have updated the permission "scp": "email Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All offline_access openid Sites.Read.All Tasks.Read User.Read User.ReadBasic.All",

Comment: Please let me know which permission I need to grant in Azure in terms of Azure (User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All) where are they in permission set

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu-MSFT please let me know about the permissions and also confirm that they required admin consent or not

Comment: @SunilSoni admin consent is not required for that. You need only User.Read.All  and User.ReadWrite.All permissions

Comment: thanks for confirmation. please describe the permissions I am unable to find in graph api (User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All ) as this one requires admin (Read all users' full profiles)

Comment: try the graph explorer to get the list of teams https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu-MSFT yes I tried that, its working fine..I can access all the teams

Comment: @SunilSoni Can you please share the source code getting the access token

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu-MSFT : here is code https://github.com/sunilsoniudaipur/Office365Authentication/blob/master/OAuth.php

Comment: @SunilSoni I hope you are mixing the version 1.0 oauth and 2.0 oauth. Can you please try this link for getting the access token using version 2.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: @SrinivasNaidu-MSFT I have updated the authentication flow, generated the token again. but no luck.. I don't understand why it is not working even with admin account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to make it work by removing the trailing "**/**" from the resource parameter when requesting an access token.

So in my case the resource

`https://graph.microsoft.com/` should be written `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAuthenticationHeader` method is calling the wrong endpoint:

```
https://login.windows.net/advaiya.com/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

You should be issuing your `HTTP POST` to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/advaiya.com/oauth2/token
```

You're also sending over `&redirect_uri=<URL>`. This value needs to match the `redirect_uri` you passed to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/advaiya.com/oauth2/authorize` when retrieving the Id Token.

Comment: Changed the endpont but no luck {
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1f9b9c3d-d39b-4ad2-84e4-60a62651a7e9",
            "date": "2018-03-22T06:21:00"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I logged-in with an administrator account. with all permissions.